# Difference between Eclipse's "clean project" and Maven's "mvn clean" in m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I use M2e + Eclipse + Maven and I would like to know what the difference is between:

- **running "mvn clean" in a terminal** and
- **running "clean project" from Eclipse**?

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From some quick tests, it seems that Eclipse's `clean project` is only clearing out the folders that are set as output folder in the project's preferences, whereas maven's `clean` is deleting the /target folder completely.

Comment: Do you know where are located the output folders and how I can access the project's preferences?

Comment: @balteo Right click on the project in the project explorer view and then click properties. On the popup, choose the 'Java Build Path' on the left, then choose the 'Source' tab. There you will find the output path for each source folder.

Answer (score 5):

I have the following entry in my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>classes/db/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
</configuration>
```

When I do a mvn clean from the command line, the directory that I want kept (classes/db in the output directory) is not deleted, as I expect.  However, when I do a Clean in Eclipse, the directory *does* get removed.

Comment: +1: This seems to confirm Giorgos Dimtsas answer, as the classes folder is normally configured as output in eclipse.