# What is the difference between "mvn clean install" & "mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse" command?

Tags: maven

I have a maven project in eclipse. I use **`mvn clean install`** for installing dependencies in `pom.xml`.

I want to know what **`mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`** command does and also the difference between these two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Eclipse's "clean project" and Maven's "mvn clean" in m2e](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853098/difference-between-eclipses-clean-project-and-mavens-mvn-clean-in-m2e)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
The second command is completely different from the first one.
First, it [deletes previously generated Eclipse files](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/clean-mojo.html) (like `.project` and `.classpath` and `.settings`) and then [generates new ones](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html), thus, effectively *updating* them. It may be useful if you introduced some changes in `pom.xml` (like new dependencies or plugins) and want Eclipse to be aware of them.

`mvn clean install`
The first command [deletes `target` directory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/usage.html) and then builds all you code and [installs artifacts into local repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: It should be noted that the m2e (maven for eclipse) plugin is vastly improved since eclipse 4.3 and so you really shouldn't need to use 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' command to generate/update eclipse projects.

Comment: @madhead The answer you gave was so valuable to me. I had an issue in visual studio code. I created a project in spring boot and i opened it with vs-code by typing `code .` in the project directory. Then I added a lombok dependency in the pom.xml file. After vs-code was having problem recognizing some packages in occurrence **javax.persistence.*** But after reading your answer I close vs-code, run **./mvnw eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse** the problem seem to be resolved. Thank you